# What is the maximum cardinality of an independent set in a finite group?

Tags: group-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$
This is sort of the dual question for [How do I find the minimum size of a generating set of a group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80774/how-do-i-find-the-minimum-size-of-a-generating-set-of-a-group).

A subset *S* of a finite group *G* is an *independent set* if for each *x* in *S*, the element *x* is not in 〈*S* ∖ {*x*}〉. For example,

- the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ has an independent set of size *n*, namely the set $\{e_1, \dotsc, e_n\}$ where $e_i$ is the sequence of length *n* with a 1 in the *i*th position and zeros elsewhere,
- the symmetric group $S_n$ has an independent set of size *n* - 1, namely the set of adjacent transpositions.

Let $\rank_u(G)$ denote the *upper rank* of *G*, defined by
$$
\rank_u(G) = \max \{ |S| \, | \, S \subseteq G \text{ and } S \text{ is independent} \}
$$

My question is what are the upper and lower bounds for the upper rank function? More formally,

1. What is the smallest function *u*(*n*) such that for each finite group *G* of order *n*, each independent set has cardinality at most *u*(*n*)?
2. What is the largest function $\ell(n)$ such that for each finite group *G* of order *n*, there is an independent set of cardinality at least $\ell(n)$?

Comment: The best general upper bound is still $\log_2 n$. But there are infinitely many groups ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$ in which the maximal size is $3$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004210

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, this is not quite what I'm asking. First, there *exists* an independent set of size *at most* $\log_2 n$, which I think follows from the proof that a finite group has a generating set of size $\log_2 n$, but that doesn't provide an upper bound. Second, I think you are describing the size of a maximal independent *generating* set, which is more restrictive than I require. I just need an independent set, not a generating one.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. The question "What is the maximum cardinality of any independent set in an arbitrary finite group?" doesn't make much sense. What I am saying is that it is not possible for an independent set in a group $G$ with $|G|=n$  to have size larger than $\log_2 n$.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the question to be more clear. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

These functions $u(n)$ and $l(n)$ will depend heavily on the prime factorization of $n$ and I doubt whether it would be possible to come up with simple formula for them that works for all $n$, or even a reasonably efficient algorithm to compute them (although that might be an interesting problem to investigate).

What we can say is that $u(n) \le \log_2 n$ for all $n$, with equality when $n$ is a power of $2$

When $n$ is a product of $k$ distinct primes (which could be the first $k$ primes) than $l(n)=k$. Groups of order $n$ are solvable, and we can find a collection of $k$ Sylow subgroups, one for each prime, and choose one element from each. So, using results from Number Theory, there are arbitrarily large integers $n$ with $l(n) > \log n/\log \log n$.

On the other hand $u(n)=1$ when $n$ is prime, and $l(n) = 1$ when $n$ is a prime power.

Comment: Can you expand on why each independent subset must have size at most $\log_2 n$?

Comment: Suppose the independent subset is $\{g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_k\}$ and let $G_i =\langle g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_i \rangle$ for $0 \le i \le k$. Then $g_i \not\in G_{i-1}$, so $|G_i| \ge 2|G_{i-1}|$ and hence $|G| = |G_k| \ge 2^k$.